# Valid seat assumption

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I'm having issue with this function question:

`x = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1],[0,1,0,0,0]]`

Function: `Book(seat)` #assuming the seat is A5
The function assumes the seat is valid in the format A, B and C. the function needs to transform the letter part of seat to an integer A = 0, B = 1 and C = 2. The string digit also needs to be changed to `"1"` → `0`, `"2"` → `1`, `"3"` → `2`, `"4"` → `3` and `"5"` → `4`. These can be used to check if the chair in the `x` list-of-lists is already booked `1` or not `0`. If it is not booked, then it should be changed to booked and the function should return `True` else it should return `False`.

My solution is

```
a = {"A":[0,0,0,0,0], "B":[0,0,0,0,1], "C":[0,1,0,0,],}
rowIndex = ["A","B","C"]
columnIndex = [1,2,3,4,5]

def book(seat):
    row = seat[0]
    column = seat[1]
    while row in rowIndex and column in columnIndex:
       if x[row][column-1] == 0:
          return True
       else: return False
```

It output `False` (seat already booked) in respective of the seat I book. I think there is an issue with my code but can't seems to figure it out.

Comment: Why using a while loop? You only need to check one seat (the one taken as input), isn't it?

Comment: please reformat your question, until then, I downvote

Comment: yes. I ask the user to input a seat, then i check with the function to see if the seat is booked or not

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
"not coming out the way I want it" is not a problem specification.

Comment: FYI: You can use a limited version of markdown to format your questions and answers quite nicely. [Here's some formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: you `Book` function should be named `book` as it is not a class

Comment: You are using loop and it is not setting the seat value to 1 if it was not previously booked. Also, all you need to do on rows, is check if the value is in `rowIndex` Since you have a dictionary, you can directly check against the keys. See code below for simpler implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code for the function:

1. There is no `x` variable defined — you called it `a` in the

   ```
   a = {"A":[0,0,0,0,0], "B":[0,0,0,0,1], "C":[0,1,0,0,],}
   ```
2. After the

   ```
   row = seat[0]
   column = seat[1]
   ```

   you then test the values in the following:

   ```
   while row in rowIndex and column in columnIndex:
   ```

   which will prevent *any* of the rest of the code from executing unless it's `True`.
3. What you need *inside* of the `while` to iterate through all the possibilities would require two `for` loops, one nested inside the other. ***However…***
4. *You don't need to loop at all* as illustrated below.

   ```
   BOOKED = 1
   x = [[0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,1], [0,1,0,0,0]]
   letter_to_index = {"A": 0, "B": 1, "C": 2}
   digit_to_index = {"1": 0, "2": 1, "3": 2, "4": 3, "5": 4}

   def book(seat):
       # Convert each seat character to integer.
       row = letter_to_index[seat[0]]
       col = digit_to_index[seat[1]]

       if x[row][col] == BOOKED:
           return False
       else:
           # Book the seat and return True
           x[row][col] = BOOKED
           return True


   if __name__ == '__main__':
       print(book('A5'))  # -> True

       # Try doing it again.
       print(book('A5'))  # -> False
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much...It really worked. the dictionary (letters_to_index and digit_to_index) is the key. I really appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler implementation of your code. You don't need to use loops. You have a dictionary. You can lookup the dictionary in a much simpler way.

```
a = {"A":[0,0,0,0,0], "B":[0,0,0,0,1], "C":[0,1,0,0,],}

def book(seat):
    r,c = seat #this allows A to be r and 5 to be C

    #check if value of r in keys of a
    #also check if seat # is within length of seats for key

    if r in a and int(c) <= len(a[r]): 
        #if valid request, then check if seat already booked
        #if not, set seat to booked by setting value to 1
        #return True
        #if already booked, return False

        if a[r][int(c)-1] == 0:
            a[r][int(c)-1] = 1
            return True
        else:
            return False

    # if not a value request, send appropriate message
    else:
        return 'invalid request'

print ('A5', book('A5'))
print ('C2', book('C2'))
print ('A7', book('A7'))
print (a)
```

Output of this will be:

```
A5 True
C2 False
A7 invalid request
{'A': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 'B': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 'C': [0, 1, 0, 0]}
```